# AWS DynamoDB batchGetItem for multiple hashKey with limit result

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to reduce the time when querying with multiple values of hasKey, thus why we are looking at batchGetItem. I did a small change in [the sample project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) as following regards of the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099845/aws-dynamodb-batch-get-request-ios) :

```
AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes * keysAndAttributes = [ AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes new ];
AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue * attributeValue1 = [ AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new ];
attributeValue1.S = @"22";
AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue * attributeValue2 = [ AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new ];
attributeValue2.S = @"18";

keysAndAttributes.keys = @[ @{ @"UserId" : attributeValue1 },
                            @{ @"UserId" : attributeValue2 } ];
keysAndAttributes.consistentRead = @YES;

AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput * batchGetItemInput = [ AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput new ];
batchGetItemInput.requestItems = @{ @"DynamoDB-OM-Sample" : keysAndAttributes };

AWSDynamoDB * awsDynamoDB = [ AWSDynamoDB defaultDynamoDB ];
[ [ awsDynamoDB batchGetItem: batchGetItemInput ]
        continueWithExecutor: [ AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor ]
                   withBlock: ^ id ( AWSTask * task ) {

                       if ( task.result ) {
                           NSLog ( @"it's working!!" );
                       }
                       else {
                           NSLog ( @"not working... " );
                       }

                       return nil;
                   } ];
```

but it keeps telling me there's a error :

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Also I do see how to set the limit in [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression.html#//api/name/limit), Can we do the same thing with batchGetItem ?

Comment: You got the solution?